# How get values into a select box from sql server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, select

Can anyone help me to populate a select box with values from sql server. I'm using MVC ASP.NET, I have a form, that is from a table X, one of it columns it's called Location and brings the city where it's from, but i have all the cities in another table Y, and want to insert the select inside that form. How should i enter the code inside the model/controller.

Here is how i set the form for table X:

Model:

```
public int Insertar(Inmueble inmueble)
        {
            SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USUARIO-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=jaera;");

            conexion.Open();

        SqlCommand comando = conexion.CreateCommand();
        comando.CommandText = "insert into Inmuebles (Titulo, Descripcion, Ambientes, Precio, Localidad, Tags, Usuario)" +
            "output inserted.Id values (@Titulo, @Descripcion, @Ambientes, @Precio, @Localidad, @Tags, @Usuario)";
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Titulo", inmueble.Titulo);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descripcion", inmueble.Descripcion);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ambientes", inmueble.Ambientes);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Precio", inmueble.Precio);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Localidad", inmueble.Localidad);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tags", inmueble.Tags);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", inmueble.Usuario);

        int nuevoId = (int)comando.ExecuteScalar();
        inmueble.Id = nuevoId;

        conexion.Close();

        return nuevoId;
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection formulario)
    {
        string Titulo = formulario["Titulo"];
        string Descripcion = formulario["Descripcion"];
        int Precio = Convert.ToInt32(formulario["Precio"]);
        int Ambientes = Convert.ToInt32(formulario["Ambientes"]);
        int Localidad = Convert.ToInt32(formulario["Localidad"]);
        string Usuario = formulario["Usuario"];
        string Tags = formulario["Tags"];

        Inmueble inmueble = new Inmueble();
        inmueble.Titulo = Titulo;
        inmueble.Localidad = Localidad;
        inmueble.Precio = Precio;
        inmueble.Ambientes = Ambientes;
        inmueble.Usuario = Usuario;
        inmueble.Descripcion = Descripcion;
        inmueble.Tags = Tags;

        InmueblesManager managerInmuebles = new InmueblesManager();
        int idInsertado = managerInmuebles.Insertar(inmueble);

        if (Request.Files.Count > 0 &&
            Request.Files[0].ContentLength > 0) //para validar que vino el archivo
        {
            string rutaFinal = Server.MapPath("~/Content/imagenes/inmuebles/" + idInsertado + ".jpg");
            Request.Files[0].SaveAs(rutaFinal);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

And this is how it looks at html code the form:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Create", "Inmuebles")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Titulo">Titulo</label>
    <input id="Titulo" name="Titulo" type="text" placeholder="Titulo" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Localidad">Localidad</label>
    <input id="Localidad" name="Localidad" type="text" placeholder="Localidad del Inmueble" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Descripcion">Descripcion</label>
    <textarea id="Descripcion" name="Descripcion" placeholder="Ingresa aqui la descripcion"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Precio">Precio</label>
    <input type="number" id="Precio" name="Precio" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Ambientes">Ambientes</label>
    <input type="number" id="Ambientes" name="Ambientes" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Tags">Tags</label>
    <input id="Tags" name="Tags" type="text" placeholder="Tags para una busqueda mas rapida" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="hidden" value="@(((ja_era.Models.Usuario)Session["usuario"]).NombreDeUsuario)" name="Usuario" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="imagen">Imagen</label>
    <input id="imagen" name="imagen" type="file" />
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Guardar" />
```

Comment: I can say that you using MVC PHP way :)

Comment: But actually i can't see `select` in your View at all =)

Comment: i want to add a select there but first i want to know if i have to add something to model or controller. i just want to know that, what i have to add in my model/controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't even attempted anything, which is kind of a no-no around these parts. I will give you a bit of general guidance, though. First, use a view model to pass data to/from the view. You should pretty much never take a `FormCollection`.

```
public class InmuebleViewModel
{
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public int Localidad { get; set; }
    public int Precio { get; set; }
    public int Ambientes { get; set; }
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Then, your get action should pass this to your view:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new InmuebleViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

Your view should use this model and utilize the HTML helpers to generate your inputs:

```
@model Namespace.To.InmuebleViewModel

...

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Titulo)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Titulo, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Titulo" } })
</div>

...
```

Finally, your post action should take this view model as a param:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(InmuebleViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

That's all just standard MVC best practice stuff. However, using the view model also gives you the ability to have a select list on it:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> FooOptions { get; set; }
```

Which you can then use in your view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Foo, Model.FooOptions)
```

You just need to populate that property in *both* your get and post actions. For that, I recommend adding a protected method to your controller that both can call to keep it dry:

```
protected void PopulateFooOptions(InmeubleViewModel model)
{
    // retrieve you options from the database, selected into an enumerable of `SelectListItem`
    model.FooOptions = options;
}
```

Then, both your get and post `Create` actions call this before returning the view:

```
PopulateFooOptions(model);
return View(model);
```

Comment: i already have all of that, just want to add the select in that code, i have the entire code of Inmueble and the Httppost and everything, i can paste all the code but its like to much of it, i have a 2 tables at sql, 1 named Inmuebles(Thisone has all about apartments, title, description, userwhopaste, location, etc) , the other named Localidades(Thisone has all locations posible in the country), i want to insert information of this table in a select box, and insert that information selected into the other table column name locations I was thinking if i can make 2 diferent commands in the model